# Iframe is loaded but not showing on Iphone

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iframe

On my Website (https://lauraseiler.com/rise-up-and-shine-university/2019), which I have built with html, css, javascript and the help of bootstrap there is a Play Button that removes an image overlaying on top of an iframe and starts playing the video from Vimeo automatically. For that I use Javascript. This worked well and is still working on Desktop but recently it is not working on IPhone. The Video starts playing but is not visible. It is visible when the Phone is turned in landscape mode but not when it is in portrait mode.

I tried to changed the z-index of the iframe and the image but that did not work.

```
<div class="container0-fluid">
    <div class="header-video">
        <picture class="video-header-img">
            <source media="(max-width: 576px)" srcset="img/sm/bg-masthead.jpg">
            <img data-src="img/lg/bg-masthead.jpg" alt="" class="lazy video-thumbnail-img" data-pin-nopin="no">
        </picture>
        <div class="video-wrapper">
            <iframe
                src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/303572289?api=1&autoplay=0&loop=0&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=0&player_id=vvimeoVid"
                id="iframePlayer" scrolling="no" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
                ontouchstart=""></iframe>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="video-play-header pulse"><img src="img/icons/play2.png"></a>
        <a href="#intro" class="scroll-down js-scroll-trigger" address="true"><span
                class="tooltiptext text-borderTop-bold">Starte
                deine Reise</span></a>
        <img class="rusu-logo" src="img/logo/RUSU_Hauptlogo_gold.png" data-pin-nopin="no">
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the iframe showing up centred after clicking the play-button and removing the image that lays on top. The error does not occur in the iOS Desktop Version in Chrome or Safari and it also works on Android phones.

Comment: Just FYI, the video doesn’t start playing for me in desktop Chrome either. The iframe shows, but then there’s an error in console, _“Uncaught (in promise) NotAllowedError: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.”_

Comment: @04FS should work again. I am still working on it and accidentally removed the allow="autoplay" attribute from the iframe.